# How can we assign different color to the same TextView at different conditions like if...else in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my android application.. an number is entered by user using EditText..
and my application tells whether the number is an integer or float type of number in a TextView..!
The problem i am facing is, i want to display the TextView in red color for integer type number and green color for float..
what should be the code for this.

the if..else condition code i want is imagined like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
if (number= interger)
{
tv.setText("integer number");
// and the color of this TextView will be RED
}
else
{
tv.setText(Float number);
// and the color of this TextView will be GREEN
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Code like this:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>integer</font> is <font color='blue'>number</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with predefined colors or defined colors in your resources
textview.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));